# Передача файла в параметр функции,с++

Tags: c++, файлы

Как передать файл в функцию вроде разобрался. Но есть непонятные моменты.

Вот решил я по ссылке передать объект `ifsream` у которого есть определенные методы.

**Вопрос**: почему при попытке манипулирования файлом с помощью методов (например `get`) в самой функции ничего не происходит?

Как будто его там и нет.

Если еще раз создать такой же объект, то все работает.
Но это не совсем то что нужно, т.к. смысл передачи файла в функцию отпадает.

Что я делаю не так?

```
int main(){

    ifstream fin("fdata.txt");
    ofstream fout("fout.txt");
    code(fin);
}

void code(ifstream &in){
    char masIn[31];
    int i=0;
    in>>masIn[i];//здесь любая попытка записать в массив не работает 
    cout<<masIn[i];
}
```

UPD:нашел проблему в функции,которая нужна для подсчета символов  в файле

```
 int shifr::filesize(ifstream &fin){
    char ch;
    int i=0;
    while(ch=fin.get()!=EOF){
    i++;
    }
 return i;
 }
```

теперь непонимание как эта функция меняет исходник файла?результат в виде непонятных символов

Comment: @HasmikGaryaka для ifstream разве он тут нужен?

Comment: Что значит "не работает"? Как вы это определили? В файле есть нужные значения?

Comment: @Harry нашел проблему в функции,только не понял как именно она все "ломает",
while(ch=fin.get()!=EOF){
   i++;
}

Comment: функция просто нужна для подсчета символов в файле

Comment: А не пробовали сначала написать БЕЗ функции?

Comment: А в чём заключается неработоспособность? Какую-то ошибку выдаёт или что?

Comment: @AlexTitov  обновил суть вопроса

Comment: Ну так вы же до конца файла дошли, больше читать нечего - вот он и не читает :) Сбросьте флаги (`clear()`), вернитесь на начало и читайте... Но для поиска размера файла уж лучше стать на конец и снять позицию - быстрее. Только файл открывать в бинарном режиме.

Comment: @Harry имеется в виду cin.clear()?его в конце функции можно вставить или как?пока не очень получается ....

Comment: точнее fin.clear

Comment: помогло ток это,тему можно закрывать,но хотелось бы на счет послед функц. узнать
fin.clear();
fin.seekg(0, ios_base::beg);

Comment: @Аркадий Тело функции filesize могло бы быть просто `fin.seekg(0, ios_base::end); return fin.tellg();` - не нужно весь файл вычитывать, работает мгновенно.

Comment: @ArtyOneSoul понял,прост не хорошо ориентируюсь во встроенных методах,а так всем спасибо,выручили)